# C# static keyword inside LINQ Select, Where,

Tags: c#, linq

I noticed it is valid to add the `static` keyword inside Linq expressions.
However it doesn't generate any different code.

Example:

```cs
list.Select(static model => model.Age).ToList();
list.Where(static model => model.Age > 18).ToList();
```

What is the purpose of the `static` keyword in this context?

[See the generated code on Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWDkQHQBkBLAOwEdMYsBmZMRAYQBsBDAZ1cQG9ZFfEjWAFwA8AWQD2AEwCmjAHyJGhIYgC8iYtIDuACgCUFPoh58QNJm1b7uMI0aVDcAQUmSdmrYgkzGXRE4BzaTVECCQAXwMTXnDo41tTGhBUf30uOKMAN2YAJ0Qc6VYAV0ZBEIdBXAB1AAtpAp0AWylZNQVmn2cgxAUwvVwAFXEBQX1DO15svJQANgAlQpKy9QrquobZxA7W1XaWxi7g3vh+oZGxjL5L3hQATh0C4tKohIm7nVmFp8EXo1iYf7UWhefawGyJRAkMqBaQUcJAA)

Generated code according to sharplab:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
public class Class
{
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

        public static Func<Model, bool> <>9__2_0;

        public static Func<Model, bool> <>9__2_1;

        internal bool <A>b__2_0(Model model)
        {
            return model.Age > 10;
        }

        internal bool <A>b__2_1(Model model)
        {
            return model.Age > 10;
        }
    }

    private List<Model> list = new List<Model>();

    public Class()
    {
        List<Model> obj = list;
        Model model = new Model();
        model.Age = 10;
        obj.Add(model);
    }

    public void A()
    {
        List<Model> value = Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Where(list, <>c.<>9__2_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__2_0 = new Func<Model, bool>(<>c.<>9.<A>b__2_0))));
        List<Model> value2 = Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Where(list, <>c.<>9__2_1 ?? (<>c.<>9__2_1 = new Func<Model, bool>(<>c.<>9.<A>b__2_1))));
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine(value2);
    }
}
public class Model
{
    public int Age;
}
```

Comment: Variable name `_` is meant to be used if you don't want to use the variable, yet you are using the variable. Prior to C# 7 `_` is a valid variable name, but since C# 7 it became a placeholder for a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) and this code will not compile there. Replace the name now, and save yourself from the future trouble.

Comment: @Dialecticus I'm asking about the `static` keyword. Anyway I updated the post to remove the `_` usage.

Comment: Consult [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/static-anonymous-functions)

Comment: Perhaps your appreciation of the difference would be improved by considering `int age = 18; list.Where(static model => model.Age > age);`

Answer (score 0):

Methods allow local inner methods, which are generally used as helpers to wrap work in separate blocks. They can also be marked as static, which means that the helper method will not have access to local variables or parameters within the outer enclosing method. So when you're using enumerator expressions like:

```
list.Select(model => model.Age)
```

The block `model => model.Age` is a lambda expression that represents something like a local helper method. The static keyword, similar to its usage in local methods or functions, means that this expression cannot access variables, parameters, or any non-static (or constant) values declared outside of itself.

For example, the following code will not compile:

```
int dummy = 0;
list.Select(static model =>
{
    dummy++; // CS8820: A static anonymous function cannot contains ref[...]
    return model.Age;
})
```

Comment: The question was about the purpose of the keyword here. So thinking in examples he needed one where using static makes sense. Your example shows only that it fails when using. So only slightly helpful.

Comment: In the expression provided, the keyword has no use since it doesn't access any local vars.
Should be removed.